Error "DeserError" while running hardhat tests on an Anvil forking node
I have a hardhat setup for both deploying and running tests of smart contracts. I wrote my unit tests using chai library and executed it using hh test --network anvil. and after a successful compilation facing this error:
ProviderError: Fork Error: DeserError { err: Error("invalid type: null, expected struct WithOtherFieldsHelper", line: 1, column: 4), text: "null" }

Realized the line which throws the error after investigation:
   export async function deployWithProxy<T>(
      contractFactory: ContractFactory,
      options: DeployOptions = {}
    ): Promise<T> {
      upgrades.silenceWarnings(); // Needed because we pass the `unsafeAllow: ["constructor"]` option.
    
      return upgrades.deployProxy(contractFactory, [], {
        kind: options.proxyType || 'uups',
        initializer: false,
        unsafeAllow: ['constructor'],
        constructorArgs: options.constructurArgs || [],
      }) as unknown as Promise<T>;
    }

By calling it:
const contract = await deployWithProxy<Contract>(ContractFactory);

Can anyone assist?
